# Passing On Values Between Functions

Tags: python

Hi i'm working on a program where a user selects an image, then it gets turned into an ASCII version of the picture, which displays in both the console and then gets saved to a notepad .txt file. The code below currently does this but I think the way I am using my returns in the functions is messing up the code. Instead of asking for the image and background colour once, it asks for it 3 times before actually drawing out the ASCII image. Then after it has drawn it, it again asks for a 4th time for the image and background colour, before finally asking for the name to give the .txt file then creating the text file.

How do I change this so that it only asks each question once without repeating itself(and what exactly is this happening?). Thanks

```
def inputs():
    image = input('What image file?')

    return (image)

def pictureConvert():

    a = inputs()
    # codefollows
```

Comment: You just wasted everyone's time with this question. -_-

Comment: Sorry I should of just made a small scale but similar example doing the some core problem. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Call the inputs function only once, and store that everywhere. This ensures that the user will be asked for input only once:

```
def inputs():
    image = input('What image file?')

    return (image)

def pictureConvert():

    a = inputs()
    # codefollows
```